# Representing the first element of a list of list of list in DataGrid XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm writing a C# WPF application where the user can barcode samples in a test rack into the app.

A rack is made up of rows. Each row contains a number of samples.

Each sample can have a list of sample details (identifier and datetime for every time the user makes a change).

Here is a picture to better visualise it: [Picture of Rack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duxBe.png)

I want to represent this in a DataGrid where the user can edit each sample in the grid.

I'm finding XAML rather difficult. I've managed to achieve what I want using code-behind (see below), but I would like to do this in XAML. Here is the [picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOvAA.png).

Is this possible?

Thank you

Additional Information:

- The number of columns and rows are user defined and will vary between racks
- Row headers are bound to the `RackPosition` property of the `Row` Class
- Column headers are bound to the `ColumnPosition` of the `Sample` class
- The text inside the DataGridCell is bound to `History[0].Identifier`
- Caliburn Micro will be used to handle the updating of samples by the user

**My Code:**

Classes:

```
public class Rack
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; } = new List <Row>();
}

public class Row
{
    public int RackPosition { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; } = new List <Sample>();
}

public class Sample
{
    public int ColumnPosition { get; set; }
    public List<SampleDetails> History { get; set; } = new List <SampleDetails>();
}

public class SampleDetails
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainDG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RackPosition}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public Rack CurrentRack { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetupDataGrid();

}

//Gets a dummy rack
public Rack GetExampleRack()
{
    Rack rack = new Rack();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Row row = new Row();
        row.Samples = new List<Sample>();
        row.RackPosition = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            row.Samples.Add(new Sample { ColumnPosition = j });
        }
        rack.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    SampleDetails testSample1 = new SampleDetails { Identifier = "Test ID 1", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };
    SampleDetails testSample2 = new SampleDetails { Identifier = "Test ID 2", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now };
    rack.Rows[0].Samples[0].History.Add(testSample1);
    rack.Rows[1].Samples[3].History.Add(testSample2);
    return rack;
}

private void SetupDataGrid()
{
    MainDG.Columns.Clear();
    CurrentRack = GetExampleRack();

    foreach (var sample in CurrentRack.Rows[0].Samples)
    {
        var sampleIndex = CurrentRack.Rows[0].Samples.IndexOf(sample);

        DataGridTemplateColumn col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = sampleIndex;

        FrameworkElementFactory textBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));

        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.BindingGroupName = ".";
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath($"Samples[{sampleIndex}].History[0].Identifier");

        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = textBox };
        dt.Seal();
        col.CellTemplate = dt;

        MainDG.Columns.Add(col);
    }
    MainDG.ItemsSource = CurrentRack.Rows;
}
```

Comment: Why not using [multidimensional-arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) ?

Comment: Is the number of samples in a row equal for all rows within a single rack?

Comment: @Keith Yes. Cfun I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking some time to think this one over, I don't think there is any practical way to do this with a `DataGrid` in XAML. I don't really think `DataGrid` was designed to handle dynamic columns in the way you need- at least, not automatically via data binding. I also don't know of any other control that would get the job done.

Even accepting that you would have to use *some* code-behind, I can't pick out any part of your code that could be easily replaced with XAML.

- There's no better way to determine the number of columns than by counting `Row.Samples`- even if you designed some component that could be used in XAML, it would just end up calling the code-behind to do this anyway.
- I thought you might at least be able to define the `DataTemplate` in XAML, but because you need to bind dynamically based on the `sampleIndex`, you would have to use something like a `MultiBinding` with a custom `IMultiValueConverter`. While that would work, I think it ultimately just makes the code more complicated- it's simpler just to leave it as is.

My other thought was to ditch the `DataGrid` altogether. I considered using an `ItemsControl`, where the `ItemTemplate` for the rows contained another `ItemsControl` for displaying the cells. Then you could bind the main `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to `Rack.Rows` and the row-level `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to `Row.Samples`. This would make all the cells for you automatically, but it gives you other problems:

- The column headers would have to be created outside the `ItemsControl`.
- Unless every cell is the same size, they wont line up. You can almost get around this by using a `Grid` with `SharedSizeGroup` columns, but `Grid` doesn't support automatic, dynamic columns from an `ItemsSource`, so we're back where we started with `DataGrid`.
- There would be no way for the user to drag and resize the columns or rows.

The list goes on, and in solving these problems you would basically end up re-creating all these features that are already present in the `DataGrid` control.

TL;DR:
I don't think there's a better, XAML-centric, way to do this.